# How can i upload image from angular 4 to Web API?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I wanna upload image from Angular 4. Call controller method in WebApiController and processing upload image. Help me please!

My component process.ts :

```js
  onUpload(file): void{
    let fileList = FileList = file;
    if(fileList.length > 0){
      let file: File = fileList[0];
      let formData: FormData = new FormData();
      formData.append('uploadFile',file, file.name);
      this.catalogService.uploadFile(formData)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.toastr.success('Ipload Image Successfully', 'Catalog Book');
      })
    }
  }
```

My service.ts

```js
  uploadFile(form: any){
    var headerOptions = new Headers({'Content-Type':'application/json'});
    var requestOptions = new RequestOptions({method: RequestMethod.Post, headers: headerOptions});
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:20952/api/UploadImage/',form,requestOptions).map(x=>x.json());
  }
```

Controller Processing from Web API

```
// POST: api/UploadImage
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult GetCatalog(Guid id)
{
    try
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;

        if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
            {
                var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
                string fileName = id + "jpg";
                var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Data/" + fileName);
                postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: what is the issue now?

Comment: can not tranmiss "file upload" to controller Web API

Comment: Are you able to call the api?you are not passing any Guid to the api also the route is different than what you are using in angular

Comment: use `[Route("api/UploadImage/"]` before the api method and pass the guid

Comment: i cannot imagine the way to transmission "file upload" to web api controller.

Answer (score -1):

This way I implement upload image to web API in project.

I share for whom concern.

```
        const formData: FormData = new FormData();
        formData.append('Image', image, image.name);
        formData.append('ComponentId', componentId);
        return this.http.post('/api/dashboard/UploadImage', formData);
```

Step by step

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/dashboard/UploadImage")]
public HttpResponseMessage UploadImage()
        {
            string imageName = null;
            var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
            //Upload Image
            var postedFile = httpRequest.Files["Image"];
            //Create custom filename
            if (postedFile != null)
            {
                imageName = new String(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(postedFile.FileName).Take(10).ToArray()).Replace(" ", "-");
                imageName = imageName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName);
                var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + imageName);
                postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
            }
}
```

HTML form

```
<form #imageForm=ngForm (ngSubmit)="OnSubmit(Image)">

                    <img [src]="imageUrl" class="imgArea">
                    <div class="image-upload">
                        <label for="file-input">
                            <img src="upload.jpg" />
                        </label>

                        <input id="file-input" #Image type="file" (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)"/>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn-large btn-submit" [disabled]="Image.value=='' || !imageForm.valid"><i class="material-icons">save</i></button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

TS file to use API

```
OnSubmit(Image) {
    this.dashboardService.uploadImage(this.componentId, this.fileToUpload).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log('done');
        Image.value = null;
        this.imageUrl = "/assets/img/logo.png";
      }
    );
  }
```

Service TS

```
uploadImage(componentId, image) {
        const formData: FormData = new FormData();
        formData.append('Image', image, image.name);
        formData.append('ComponentId', componentId);
        return this.http.post('/api/dashboard/UploadImage', formData);
    }
```